# .htaccess made my URL without slash at the end "Not Found"

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

```
#RewriteEngine On

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Use the following rule if you want to make the page like a directory
RewriteRule ^user/(!(profile.php))$ user/$1/ [R=301,L]

# The following rule does the rewrite.
RewriteRule ^user/(.+)/$ profile.php?id=$1

# The following rewrite the other way round:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/profile.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD|TRACE)\ /profile.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^profile.php$ user/%1?

<files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/mysite\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

When I access this URL: 
http://mysite.com/user/john/ - This totally works perfectly!
But when I acces the URL without slash at the end, like this: http://mysite.com/user/john browser tells me this error:

[image]

What should I do here? Your help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded!

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule here:

```
RewriteRule ^user/(!(profile.php))$ user/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Doesn't seem to be working for me. Try changing it to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/user/profile.php
RewriteRule ^user/(.*[^/])$ user/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Since your original rule isn't matching, requests for `http://mysite.com/user/john` is slipping through the rules unchanged and thus not handled by profile.php.

Comment: So what you did here is to force the URL to have a slash at the end, right? :)

Comment: @ElsonSolano Yes, it looks like your original rule was trying to do that, and your rewrite rule `RewriteRule ^user/(.+)/$ profile.php?id=$1` specifically matches against a trailing slash, so without it, nothing happens.